# Equivalent Java functions to C functions in network programming

Tags: java, c, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I'm doing a comparison between some C functions used in network programming, and their Java counterpart. Most of them I can find in documents about `Socket`, `ServerSocket`, `InetAddress` classes.

However I can't seem to find `listen()`, `recv()`, `send()` and `getaddrinfo()` in Java. As far as I go, I see that most Java client-server programs do not require them, as you can just write the byte/message and flush them directly to the other end, using `flush()` or `PrintWriter()`.

Do I understand this right, and are there any equivalent functions to those three?

Comment: You can just read Java API carefully to see that (for example) backlog control can be made a ServerSocket construction... Reading and writing is observable through the service socket returned from `accept()`. Please make some effort by reading documentation first.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a `ServerSocket`, the underlying `listen` function gets called when you bind to a port, either through the constructor or though the `bind` method.

The `recv` and `send` functions are called by reading from and writing to the InputStream and OutputStream respectively that are attached to a `Socket` instance and returned by the `getInputStream` and `getOutputStream` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Listening and receiving can be implemented in multiple different ways. Java is object-oriented so the logic is usually represented by a specific object type.

Take a look at [Reading from and Writing to a Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) tutorial which gives a few examples on working with sockets, e.g. using `InputStream` and `OutputStream` to interact with `Socket`:

```
try (
  Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
  PrintWriter out =
      new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
  BufferedReader in =
      new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
  BufferedReader stdIn =
      new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(System.in))
)
```